# Determining pixel size based on LiDAR point cloud density

Tags: raster, dem, lidar, point-cloud

I have a point cloud with a density of 8 points/m². I would like to generate a digital elevation model (DEM) from it, but I don't know what resolution to set as the raster pixel.

So I would like to know if there are any formulas that can be used to calculate this or  the raster resolution is subjective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

The value for the raster resolution should be a bit more then 0.333 m, ca. around **0.34 meters**. See below why.

### Value for 9 regularily spaced points per square meter

Consider the image below and suppose the black square is 1m x 1m. Subdividing it in 9 equally sized squares (green dotted line) and getting the centroids of each (red dots), you have 9 points per square meter. As can be seen, each point has a distance from each other correspoinding to 1/3 of the side length of the black square, thus 1/3 meters = **0.333 meters**.

### Value for 8 regularily spaced points per square meter

For 8 more or less regularily distributed points, draw a regular polygon with 7 with center at the centroid of the large square and 7 sides/edges (blue dotted line). The 7 nodes (vertices) of the polygon together with it's centroid return 8 points (blue stars). As you can see, their distance from each other is slightly larger, but not much (the two stars at the bottom).

So to give an answer: set a value of like **0.35 meters** for pixel resution.

[image]

### Calculating experimentally the mean distance of 8 more or less evenly distributed points

Using antother approach, I generated 500 random points for each of the 9 smaller squares, applied K-means clustering with `Number of clusters` = 8, created voronoi polygons, aggregated them based on the field `CLUSTER_ID` to get 8 more or less evently subparts (red outlined in the next screenshot) of the large square and created the centroid of each of these polygons (red star). Then I calculated the mean distance from each of these centroid to its two nearest neighbors (see below for the expression used). Result: **0.339 meters**. If using the pole of inaccessability instead of the centroid, the value is **0.346 meters**.

[image]

The expression used to calculate the mean distance from each of the red stars to the two nearest neighbors. The expression is applied to the aggregated voronoi polygons:

```
mean( 
    with_variable(
        'array',
        array_sort(
            array_foreach(
                overlay_nearest (@layer, centroid ($geometry), limit:=8),
                length (make_line (centroid ($geometry), @element))
            )
        ),
        (@array[0] + @array[1] )/2
    )
)
```

*Centroids (white=red stars in the screenshot above) and poles of inaccessability (red) from the aggregated voronoi polygons (outlined in fine red line): 8 more or less evenly distributed points:*

[image]